# C# asp.net - Context corelations with List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I got a little issue with the lambda query.

I have 2 tables: Inventory and Articles. Also, I've created a list of parts I want to show.

```
public class SteelSheet
{
    public string Part { get; set; }
    public float Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

```
var sheetTest = _context.Inventories.Include(x => x.Article)......;
```

Articles include the field Part. I want to show data from Inventories and Articles which contain only Parts from steelSheet list.

edit:

```
    public class Inventory
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public int Stock { get; set; }

        public int ArticleID { get; set; }

        public Article Article { get; set; }

    }
```

```
    public class Article
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Part { get; set; }

        public float Price { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Inventory> Inventory { get; set; }
    }
```

```
steelSheet.Add(new SteelSheet() { Part = "PART0001", Quantity = "8" });
steelSheet.Add(new SteelSheet() { Part = "PART0002", Quantity = "3" });
```

SteelSheet is a list of parts which i want to show (i generete this list using another functions) But also i want to see price from Article and Stock from inventory.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. I'm sorry, but you need to be more specific. What do you mean with "show data"? What data? Show how? How is `Part` related to `Articles` and `Inventory`? What's `Quantity` doing here?

Comment: Your code is not full. Please show your Inventory and Article Entity Models.

Comment: I add my model in main post.

Comment: Where is `Quantity` in your `Article` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From you question there seems no need to base the query on `Inventory`. The Article matches the Part number and each article contains a list of associated inventories.

The straightforward query would be

```cs
var parts = steelSheet.Select(s => s.Part).ToArray();
var matchingArticles = _context.Articles
    .Where(a => parts.Contains(a.Part))
    [.Select(a => [projection]]
    [.ToList()/.ToArray()];
```

Things like `.Include(a => a.Inventory)` are only required if you are using eager loading. [read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/).